# Числовой формат в xml

Tags: xml, xls

Доброго времени суток. Сейчас составляю xml для создания .xls файла, но не могу правильно задать числовой формат. Вот код:

```
<Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="Dengi" ss:Name="Dengi">
        <NumberFormat ss:Format="# ###.00" />
    </Style>
</Styles>
...
<Cell ss:StyleID="Dengi"><Data ss:Type="Number">{cost}</Data></Cell>
```

Однако числа все равно отображаются в виде `12345,67`. Как правильно указать документу, что разделитель разрядов - пробел, а десятичный разделитель - точка?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Excel использует региональные настройки винды, там задается дробный разделитель и т.д. А в числовом формате Вы можете указать сколько символом после дробного разделителя.

Comment: А эти настройки можно как-то перекрыть или выбрать другие?

Comment: А мне кажется, что запятая появляется при подстановке {cost}, на что влияют региональные настройки, используемые вашей средой.

Comment: При подстановке `{cost}` заменяется int'ом, к примеру, `12345`.

Comment: @ling, нужны подробности. Какой вид имеет выходной xml?

Comment: @maxleo, к примеру, [http://jsfiddle.net/KKtGN/1/][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/KKtGN/1/

Comment: @ling, все как вы заказывали. Остальное - не ваши проблемы. Если нужен вид, а не значения, то пишите текстом.